# How to check connectivity of a directed graph in Python?

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

Is there any way in Python's networkx to check for connectivity of a directed graph? If not in networkx, how else may this be achieved in Python?

Comment: There is the subpackage [`networkx.connectivity`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/connectivity.html) — have you checked there?

Comment: I believe that only operates on undirected graphs. I think the is_strongly_connected function will provide me with what I am seeking. I would really like to know how this works though? i.e. what algorithms does it use to calculate the result?

Comment: Nevermind, found it here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/components/strongly_connected.html